# ddev: "Failed to run docker-compose..." error

Tags: docker, typo3, ddev

When I try to start my ddev project, I face the following error:

"Failed to start projectname.com: Failed to run docker-compose [...]"

My **.ddev/config.yaml** looks like this:

```
name: projectname.com
type: typo3
docroot: web/
php_version: "7.1"
webserver_type: apache-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
provider: default
use_dns_when_possible: true
hooks:
  post-start:
    - exec: composer install -d /var/www/html

webimage_extra_packages: [pdftk]
```

OS: MacOS

ddev version: 1.16.6

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't think I can offer any help if you don't show the full error message. 

Please run the diagnostic script in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/test_ddev.sh and post the results as a gist in gist.github.com and it will help. 

Also, please upgrade your ddev to at least v1.16.7, but preferably to current v1.17.2

Most likely your problem is the expired deb.sury.org key that was in v1.16.6. You can fix it by upgrading or by removing the `webimage_extra_packages` line.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to [v1.16.7](https://github.com/drud/ddev/releases/tag/v1.16.7) at least, as there was an expired key in v1.16.6, which is why v1.16.7 was released.

As a general practice, please try to use the current stable version of software when asking for support.