# ddev failed to start or restart with a "docker Read timed out"

Tags: macos, docker, ddev

I got a problem when I start a 2nd ddev container or restart a running ddev container. Then I more and more often run into the following error:

> Failed to start project for custom command: Failed to run docker-compose [-f /Users/montea/tmp/tryddevproject-10532/.ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml up --build -d], err='exit status 1', stdout='Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

At the time of writing I have the latest Version of

- Docker Desktop Version 3.3.3 (64133)
- ddev 1.17.2

Running on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7

I run the diagnostic script as it is said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370791/ddev-failed-to-run-docker-compose-error)

[Here is the gist for ddev 1.17.2](https://gist.github.com/Mon-Tea/45b5d71201dbac6add1f8b3d34413cd2)

[Here is the gist for ddev 1.17.1 (for reference)](https://gist.github.com/Mon-Tea/e5a2a1672ba9cd3efe513055b66981a5)

If I restart Docker it first works, but then after a while the problem appears again.

Sometimes the Docker restart doesn't work at all. Then it could help if I do `ddev poweroff` and `ddev start` again.

Perhaps this is also a problem: my oldest ddev project was 1.8.0 my newest is 1.17.2 …

**Edit/Update:**

After the try-fixes in my answer:

I was too hectic and started two ddev containers at the same time. Got this Error.

> Failed to start project: failed to start ddev-router: Failed to run docker-compose [-f /Users/montea/.ddev/.router-compose-full.yaml -p ddev-router up -d], err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr='Top level object in '/Users/montea/.ddev/.router-compose-full.yaml' needs to be an object not '<class 'NoneType'>'.'

But after that I started the container again, that "crashed", and everything works.

The only thing is, every time I start my mac and start ddev I run into this error:

> Failed to start project2: ddev-router failed to become ready; debug with 'docker logs ddev-router'; logOutput=container was previously healthy, so sleeping 59 seconds before continuing healthcheck...  nginx config valid:OK  ddev nginx config:generated nginx healthcheck endpoint:OK ddev-router is healthy with 3 upstreams, err=container /ddev-router unhealthy: container was previously healthy, so sleeping 59 seconds before continuing healthcheck...  nginx config valid:OK  ddev nginx config:generated nginx healthcheck endpoint:OK ddev-router is healthy with 3 upstreams

After `ddev poweroff` and ddev start again, it works. But the error appears every day.

Comment: Thanks for that, and especially for providing the gist of the diagnostic script. It looks like your Docker Desktop is just broken, or perhaps you have networking difficulties. If I were you I would 1) reboot, 2) Turn off any firewall and virus checker temporarily 3) Reset docker to factory defaults (you will lose any databases, so export or snapshot first), 4) completely uninstall and reinstall docker desktop.

There are lots more suggestions in https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this was only a Docker issue. So I followed these steps:

- Reboot (helps temporay)
- Turn off the firewall (was not possible, because my admins don't like that)
- Backup all ddev databases
- Clean / Purge data
- Reset docker to factory defaults

Nothing from the above worked, so Docker wants the "hard way". So I decided to remove/uninstall Docker from my MAC.

- Docker removed from Applications
- com.docker.docker removed from Library/Containers
- com.docker.helper removed from Library/Application Scripts
- com.docker.docker removed from Library/Caches
- group.com.docker removed from Library/Group Containers
- Docker Desktop removed from Library/Application Support

I found a brew installed docker, so I removed that also:

- brew uninstall docker
- Restart MAC
- Install Docker via https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop

Downloaded Docker.dmg and installed it. Now I hope this helps others too, who run into this issue.

---

After a while of testing I think the fix is a bundle of

- remove and reinstall docker (like above)
- reinstalling docker

and every eob I do

- **ddev poweroff**

No more problems…